# probability Markov's inequality: prove or disprove

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

let X be a non-negative random variable.
prove or disprove:
$$27E(X) > 64P(X > e)$$

Can I take a random variable that always gives 0 and disproves it? Or it is proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(X=0)=1$, then we have $E(X)=0$ and $P(X > e)=0$.

Hence, yes, you get $0 > 0$, you have disproved the statement.